# Why does my UDP pinger client only timeout?

Tags: python, sockets

I've made a UDP Pinger server side, however this UDP Pinger client only sends request time outs. I'm trying to make a pinger that sends 10 pings to the server.

```
import time
from socket import *

serverName = ''
serverPort = 12000

ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

ClientSocket.settimeout(1)

ping = 1

message = 'ping'
counter = 10
i = 0
remain = counter - i

while counter < i :
        i = i + 1
addr = ("", 120000)

start = time.time() 
ClientSocket.sendto(message, (serverName, 
serverPort))

while ping < 11:

try:
        message, server = ClientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
        end = time.time()
        elapsed = end - start
        print (message + " " + str(ping) + " " + 
        str(elapsed))

    except timeout:
        print ('REQUEST TIMED OUT')
 ping = ping + 1
```

Comment: Can you add error message? There is no declaration for timeout either